# Idris won't expand `mult` in proof of exponent law

Tags: idris, theorem-proving

I'm trying to write a proof that `2^n * 2^m = 2^(n+m)` in Idris. Right now I have this:

```
expLaw : (power 2 n) * (power 2 m) = power 2 (n + m)
expLaw {n=Z} {m} = plusZeroRightNeutral (power 2 m)
expLaw {n=S n'} {m=m'} = 
  trans (multAssociative 2 (power 2 n') (power 2 m')) $ 
  cong {f=mult 2} $ expLaw {n=n'} {m=m'}
```

This gives me the error:

```
When checking an application of function trans:
        Type mismatch between
                mult 2 (power 2 n' * power 2 m') = mult 2 (power 2 (n' + m')) (Type of cong powExp)
        and
                mult (mult 2 (power 2 n')) (power 2 m') = plus (power 2 (plus n' m')) (plus (power 2 (plus n' m')) 0) (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        mult 2 (power 2 (n' + m'))
                and
                        plus (power 2 (plus n' m')) (plus (power 2 (plus n' m')) 0)
```

As far as I can tell, this is essentially saying that it is seeing a `2 * 2^(n+m)` where it wants a `2^(n+m) + (2^(n+m) + 0)`. However, by the definition of mult, the former should trivially reduce to the latter. In particular, the following compiles without problem:

```
foo : 2 * a = a + (a + 0)
foo = Refl
```

To me, this indicates that the expansion is working as I would expect. But for some reason, in my implementation of `expLaw`, the compiler gets stuck. I'm wondering if it might have something to do with the use of `mult` and `plus` versus `*` and `+`, but I'm not sure. How can I fix this?

Alternatively, if anyone has a better way to implement `expLaw` I'd be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to add proofs step by step with `let … in …` blocks, so you can easily inspect the types. The error occures under `trans`, so given

```
expLaw : (power 2 n) * (power 2 m) = power 2 (n + m)
expLaw {n=Z} {m} = plusZeroRightNeutral (power 2 m)
expLaw {n=S n'} {m=m'} =
  let prf1 = cong {f=mult 2} $ expLaw {n=n'} {m=m'} in
  let prf2 = multAssociative 2 (power 2 n') (power 2 m') in
  ?hole

> :t hole
  m' : Nat
  n' : Nat
  prf1 : plus (mult (power 2 n') (power 2 m'))
              (plus (mult (power 2 n') (power 2 m')) 0) =
         plus (power 2 (plus n' m')) (plus (power 2 (plus n' m')) 0)
  prf2 : plus (mult (power 2 n') (power 2 m'))
              (plus (mult (power 2 n') (power 2 m')) 0) =
         mult (plus (power 2 n') (plus (power 2 n') 0)) (power 2 m')
--------------------------------------
hole : mult (plus (power 2 n') (plus (power 2 n') 0)) (power 2 m') =
       plus (power 2 (plus n' m')) (plus (power 2 (plus n' m')) 0)
```

You can see that the order of the equalities `prf2 : a = b`, `prf1 : a = c` don't match up with `trans : (a = b) -> (b = c) -> a = c`. But with a simple `sym : (a = b) -> b = a` it works. So you almost had it. :-)

```
 …
 let prf3 = trans (sym prf2) prf1 in
 prf3
```